# Git-hub pages, Jekyll won't install

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to install Jekyll for Github Pages, unfortunately it returns the following:

```
>$ gem install github-pages

>Fetching: RedCloth-4.2.9.gem (100%)
>
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>    
Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/RedCloth-4.2.9.gem
```

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.4, and I installed RVM as well as command line tools in xcode, but I'm stuck there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? `ruby --version`

Comment: do you not need to use `sudo gem install github-pages` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to do a `sudo gem install`